# Kivy StringProperty not updating

Tags: python, kivy

My app at button press should get a path in one screen and display that path in another screen in a label.

Right now I indeed get the path and assign it to a global variable but when I change screen the Label doesn't update with the global variable value.

In first Screen you button press and get the file path, you can see that the variables get updated, but on second screen the value didn't get updated.

How can I update the value of screen 2?

How should I approach this problem if not with global variables?

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
import cv2
import time
import datetime
import os

from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from tkinter import Tk
filepath = 'no update?'
Config.set('graphics', 'resizable', '0')
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '500')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '200')
Config.write()

class SelectFileScreen(MDScreen):
    global filepath
    filepath3 = StringProperty('Your file path')
    def get_image_one(self):
        Tk().withdraw() 
        filename = askopenfilename(
            initialdir = f"{os.getcwd()}",
            title = "Select a File",
        )
        self.filepath3 = filename
        filepath = filename
        #variables indeed get updated, prints the new path instead of "no update?"
        print('file path: '+filepath)
        print('file path3: '+self.filepath3)
        self.manager.current = 'settings'
class GetFramesScreen(MDScreen):
   
    frame_location = StringProperty(f"{os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'),'Desktop')}")
    #filepath2 doesnt get updated with the new filepath value
    filepath2 = StringProperty(filepath)

    
    def get_frames(self):
        if self.filepath2 == 'Your file path':
            self.filepath2 = 'Select a file first'
        else:
            self.filepath2 = filepath
            testdir = os.path.join(self.frame_location,os.path.basename(self.filepath)).replace('.', '_').replace('\01', '01')
            os.mkdir(testdir)
            vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(self.filepath)
            fps= vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS)
            frame_count = vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)
            capduration = int(frame_count/fps)
            video_time = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=capduration))
            print(video_time)
            success,frame = vidcap.read()
            cont = 1
            n_extracted_frames = 0
            while success:
                if cont == 1 or cont%int(fps) == 0:
                    seconds1 = (vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC))/(1000)
                    video_time2 = str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=seconds1))
                    x = video_time2.replace(':','.')
                    formatted = f"frame{cont}_{x}.jpg"
                    print(formatted)
                    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(testdir,formatted),frame)
                    n_extracted_frames+=1
                success,frame = vidcap.read()
                cont+=1
            print(n_extracted_frames)
   


class GetframesApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(SelectFileScreen(name='menu'))
        sm.add_widget(GetFramesScreen(name='settings'))

        return sm

GetframesApp().run()
```

kv file:

```
<SelectFileScreen>:
    MDRaisedButton:
        text: 'Select file'
        md_bg_color: 1, 0, 1, 1
        on_press: root.get_image_one()
            

<GetFramesScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        id: myroot
        MDLabel:
            text: root.filepath2
            halign: "center"
        MDProgressBar:
            value: 50
        MDStackLayout:
            adaptive_height: True
            orientation: 'rl-tb'
            MDRaisedButton:
                text: 'Get frames'
            
                md_bg_color: 1, 0, 1, 1
                on_press: root.filepath
```

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for that `Label` to get updated automatically, you can use a `StringProperty`. A convenient place for that `StringProperty` is in the `MDApp`, like this:

```
class GetframesApp(MDApp):
    app_filepath = StringProperty('Not Set')
```

Then use that in your `kv`:

```
    MDLabel:
        text: app.app_filepath
        halign: "center"
```

And set its value in the `get_image_one()` method:

```
def get_image_one(self):
    Tk().withdraw()
    filename = askopenfilename(
        initialdir=f"{os.getcwd()}",
        title="Select a File",
    )
    MDApp.get_running_app().app_filepath = filename
    self.manager.current = 'settings'
```